# connect Ms Access to java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, apache-poi

I extracted data from excel using poi api. Now I want to store the data in access please clarify

Comment: Why would you do that when you can go directly from Excel to Access?

Comment: Try to use ucanaccess instead of odbc just follow this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the point, you just want to "convert" Excel to MSAccess using Java code? Here are the steps:

1) Extract data from Excel into Java objects (List, String, Number, Javabean, etc).
2) Insert the data in flavor of those Java objects into MSAccess.

That's basically all. For 1) you can use under each the Apache POI as you already found out. For 2) you can use the JDBC. I think your problem is more that you don't understand what JDBC is and how to work with it. In that case you may find the [Sun's JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) useful. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [JetProxy](http://jmatrix.net/content/jetproxy_client.jsp) -- a JDBC driver interfacing to Jet (the internal name of Microsoft Access's own quasi-relational sort-of-SQL DB engine). There are other products much in the same vein, but I have no personal experience to help suggest which product is best for your purposes -- just try a few!-)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [commercial JDBC drivers by HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html) or the [JDBC-ODBC bridge by Sun](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html)